# Model connections is not working properly - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to display a tag that is selected by the user. The tag name is in the tags table. The tagpost table has the mapping between the tag and the user.

The following is the User model, where the primary key in users table is id, and var_id can be many types and 2 is for users (not sure if the below where condition is correct):

```
public function tagpost()
    {

      return $this->hasMany('App\tagpost', 'var_id')->where('type',2);
    }
```

The following is the tagpost model:

```
     public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\tag','id');
    }

        public function users()
    {

      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

The following is the tag model :

```
 public function tagposts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\tagpost', 'var_id');
    }
```

The following query is not working in the blade :

```
<option>{{ Auth::user()->tagpost()->tags()->select('t_name')->first()->t_name}} </option>
```

Error in blade :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tags()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tagpost is just the relation table why don’t you define a method tags() on the User model, using the tagposts table as the pivot so you can just do Auth::user()->tags()?

Your code won’t work because ->tagpost() returns the Relation itself and not the tagpost models...

Comment: I'm not aware of the pivot syntax. Can you please add an example ?

Comment: Check laravel docs for many to many relations.  Would send you details, but working on mobile here ;-).  You can define relation between user and tags directly as a many-to-many which makes much more sense in your context!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the relations as method whereas they should be called as property like this. Also i suggest you the  [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)

```
<option>{{ Auth::user()->tagpost->tags->select('t_name')->first()->t_name}} </option>
```